# Why pump will not shut off?

Tags: plumbing

What I got: old Sears hyddopeumatic water tank, just bought a new Drummond 1 horse owner pump, the pump was set at 30/50 psi. But the pump will not shut off after even the pressure gauge reads at 55 or close to 60. (The tank has a cap on the air tap into the tank?)

Please note, the outlet of the rank has a shut off valve so no water was released into the house pipe. No leaks finding either.

Run a few times and saw the water enter into pressure gauge screen.

Comment: Check your pressure switch.  Sometimes when you open the system up you get some debris in the line which can plug the switch and keep it from registering the pressure and shutting off.  Also check that the contacts in the switch haven't "welded" themselves together.

Comment: Hi jwh20, thank you very much! Yes, I checked the switch although did not see any, but I readjust the spring higher, and it shuts off now at 50 and starts at 30. . It is brand new but do not know it was off so much. Thank you for the tips. 

Comment: @Teo If jwh20 provided the right answer for you, be sure to accept it so they get the points.

Answer (score 1):

Check your pressure switch. Sometimes when you open the system up you get some debris in the line which can plug the switch and keep it from registering the pressure and shutting off. Also check that the contacts in the switch haven't "welded" themselves together.